# Training signature file for supervised classification in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, classification

I want to do supervised classification in ArcGIS 9.3. I have a 321RGB composite of a pretty good quality which I want to use for supervised classification.

How can I create signature file which contains training sites, and how do I create training sites?

I do know what qualities are needed regarding the areas and the number of areas (number, all possible categories, spectrally separable etc.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have tried supervised classification in ArcGIS.

Firstly I would say that it is not the best software for classification.

As I did it, you can create training sites as points. Just create a shapefile (or geodatabase), add *Integer* field, click points over your image and assign classes as numbers. (I think you can also use polygon shapefile).

[image: Training sites]

For signatures, go to *ArcToolbox > Spatial Analyst Tools > Multivariate > Create Signatures*. There just put your bands and training points.

[image: Signatures]

ArcGIS doesn't show you the resulting signature file, however it is ASCII file and you can look inside, for example using Notepad++. For each band you can see something like this:

```
#  Class ID     Number of Cells    Class Name
        1                 5         
# Layers             1             2             3
# Means    
                 74.20000      98.80000      69.60000
# Covariance
    1            67.70000      95.30000     211.60000
    2            95.30000     149.20000     354.40000
    3           211.60000     354.40000     903.80000
# -------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If you wish, you can plot the Means manually to see if they are separated, for example in Excel.

You can do a dendrogram for your classes *Spatial Analyst Tools > Multivariate > Dendrogram*.

```
           Distances between Pairs of Combined Classes
                  (in the sequence of merging)

             Remaining   Merged       Between-Class
               Class      Class          Distance
           -----------------------------------------
                  1          3            1.882214
                  1          4            2.706293
                  1          2           12.502329
           -----------------------------------------

           Dendrogram of c:\2tmp\creates_shallow.gsg

C   DISTANCE
L
A
S  0       1.4     2.8     4.2     5.6     6.9     8.3     9.7    11.1    12.5
S  |-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|

  3 ---------|
             |----|
  1 ---------|    |--------------------------------------------------------|
                  |                                                        |
  4 --------------|                                                        |-
                                                                           |
  2 -----------------------------------------------------------------------|

   |-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
   0       1.4     2.8     4.2     5.6     6.9     8.3     9.7    11.1    12.5
```

Then you do actually classification *Multivariate > Maximum Likelihood Classification*. There you have only two tunable options: to say, how much uncertain pixels will remain unclassified (rejected), and probability weighting for classes; and request a confidence raster.

[image]

And the result looks like this:

[image]

For theorical information check [classification help](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Performing_the_classification) and [signature help](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Producing_signature_files,_class_and_cluster_analysis).

Actually, after several attempts I switched to Remote Sensing software.

Comment: Instead of points, you can also create polygon samples for use in the creation of signatures.